# $f$ is a polynomial on $\mathbb{R}, f(2x)=f'(x)f''(x)$ I need to find out the value of $f(3)$

Tags: polynomials

Given that $f$ is a polynomial on $\mathbb{R}, f(2x)=f'(x)f''(x)$ I need to find out the value of $f(3)$

could anyone just give me hint?

Comment: It is not entirely clear from the comments, but I assume that beside the $f(x)=0$ you found the $f(x)=\frac{4x^3}{9}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the zero polynomial satisfies this condition.

If we suppose that $f$ is not the zero polynomial, then $f$ has degree at least $2$. (Why?) In fact, comparing the degrees of the left and right side, $f$ must have degree $3$. (Why?) Can you take it from there?

Comment: $n=n-1+n-2\Rightarrow n=3$

Comment: Bingo. Were you able to conclude that it couldn't be a cubic, then?

Comment: yaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Comment: Good.${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Incidentally, if you want to leave a shorter comment, as I just did, you can pad it with extra invisible characters like so: `${}{}{}{}{}$`

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Compare the degrees and the leading coefficients of the LHS and the RHS.